# Call C++ DLL from VBA

Tags: c++, excel, vba, visual-studio, dll

I try to create a C++ DLL on Visual Studio. I want to call this DLL from VBA (Excel). I created 3 functions `DllRegisterServer()`, `DllUnregisterServer()`, `runApp()`.

When I run `regsvr32 DLL1.dll` (the name of my DLL), the `DLLRegisterServer()` function was running fine. The `runApp()` function is my test function.
But from VBA, I have an error when I call my DLL:

[image]

In Visual Studio, I created a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) project.

Here is my DLL1.cpp:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dll1.h"

DWORD __stdcall DllRegisterServer() {
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
    NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Dans DLLRegisterServer", (LPCWSTR)L"Test",MB_OK |  
    MB_ICONWARNING);

return 0;
}

DWORD __stdcall DllUnregisterServer() {
    return 0;
}

DWORD __stdcall runApp() {
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"Fonction runApp", (LPCWSTR)L"Test_App",
        MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING
   );
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my DLL1.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

extern "C" DWORD __stdcall DllRegisterServer();
extern "C" DWORD __stdcall DllUnregisterServer();
extern "C" DWORD __stdcall runApp();
```

Here is my Source.def:

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
  DllRegisterServer PRIVATE
  DllUnregisterServer PRIVATE
  runApp
```

My DLL builds fine with no error and no warning.
I placed my VBA project in same folder than my DLL1.dll file.
Here is my VBA script:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Function runApp Lib "Dll1.dll" () As LongPtr

Public Sub testRunApp()
    Dim lRetCode As LongPtr
    lRetCode = runApp
    MsgBox "runApp a retourné le code " & lRetCode, vbOKOnly Or vbSystemModal Or vbInformation, "test de DLL"
End Sub
```

How to do?

Comment: If you don't use the full path (c:\foo\bar\baz\dll1.dll) then you must put the DLL in a place where Excel can find it.  Not many attractive locations, c:\windows and PATH are both quite ugly.  Consider putting it the Office install folder, same place where Excel.exe is stored.

Comment: Your dll does not appear to export COM objects, so you don't need to register it (and doing so will achieve nothing for you). `runApp` should be declared `As Long` on the VBA side because that is what `DWORD` is. Otherwise, unless you provide a full path to `Dll1.dll`, you need to either place it in one of the [searched directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) or call [`SetDllDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya) before first call to `runApp`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call every DLL from VBA, only ActiveX DLL can be called.